# How to specify a required parameter only if an optional switch is used

Tags: powershell

I am processing CSV files to insert a column. If the file has a header record of field names (-hasheader), then I also need a column name (-new_label) value.

I put both of these parameters into a parameter set, but -new_label should not be required if -hasheader is not used. How can I cause -new_label to not be required unless -hasheader is used? Is this where DynamicParam must be used?

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, position=0)]
    [string]$csv_in
    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, position=1)]
    [string]$csv_out
    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, position=2)]
    [string]$column
    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, position=3)]
    [string]$new_value
    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="HeaderRecord")]
    [switch]$hasheader
    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="HeaderRecord")]
    [string]$new_label
    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$delimiter = ','
    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$quote = '"'
)
```

I also tried the following. PowerShell did not complain about the Mandatory value being a script block, but it still required the new_label parameter.

```
,[Parameter(Mandatory={$hasheader -eq $true}, ParameterSetName="HeaderRecord")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the default parameter set something other than `HeaderRecord`:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='foo')]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [string]$csv_in,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
    [string]$csv_out,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
    [string]$column,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3)]
    [string]$new_value,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="HeaderRecord")]
    [switch]$hasheader,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="HeaderRecord")]
    [string]$new_label,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$delimiter = ',',

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$quote = '"'
)
```